# For html, how can I get a suburl within a page?

Tags: html

In the official doc in https://discord.js.org when on click on one of the parameters, the url on top will change to the url to the parameter. How do I do that in html(for a table)?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about basic links? Just use `<a href="">Link</a>`? If you have a different page, the browser will automatically change what it displays (usually to reflect the name). You *can* alter this behaviour, but you'll need to be much more specific about *exactly* what you want for help in that regard.

Comment: thank you for the info@ let me try this

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that with HTML alone. The closest you can come is to use a regular link.

The Discord documentation is using *masses of JavaScript* to achieve the effect it has. Exactly what it is using is hard to tell, but it might be [React](https://reactjs.org/) with [HashRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md).

Comment: Thank you For Helping me